# Websphere MQ using 100% CPU in .NET app

Tags: c#, .net, websphere, ibm-mq

I have a .NET application that uses WebSphere MQ as a reliable publish/subscribe middleware, and I'm having problems when sending a queue of subsequent messages from server to client. The server uses an XMSClient object from [this library](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mqttdotnet/), publishes a message and, when delivery has been acknowledged, checks for a new one and publishes that, until none are left to publish, at which point it waits for 30 seconds and will poll for more messages to send. However, I'm finding that what regularly happens is that when I have a queue of messages (as few as 25), WebSphere will suddenly push CPU usage to 100% which I can't recover from unless I use MQ Explorer and purge the channel. This can cause catastrophic problems with my program: does anyone know what causes this and a way to get around it?

Thanks

Comment: WMQ runs a number processes. Can you let us know which of those process(es) are consuming 100% CPU. Also MQTTDotnet assembly you are using are for clients only. Not sure how they can be used from MQ server side.

Comment: Hi, the process listed as taking the most CPU are System and java.exe - approx 56% and 41% respectively. Also: "Also MQTTDotnet assembly you are using are for clients only." - Can you please clarify this statement? I'm using an MQTTClient object from that library for the client, and XMSClient object for the server.

Answer (score 0):

Now I think I understand your scenario little better. I believe you are using XMS.NET assembly for your server application that publishes messages to MQTT client application developed using [this library](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mqttdotnet/). At some stage the WebSphere MQ channel for MQTT goes into high CPU utilization.

You have have mentioned System and Java.exe take up lot CPU. You can safely ignore the CPU usage of System. It's the Java.exe that is causing the high CPU usage. It appears that at some point the MQTT channel is going to a loop consuming high CPU. It is possible that it's in constant conversation with your MQTT client application. The problem could be with your MQTT client application also. So my suggestion would be to isolate the problem by using some other MQTT client application and see if the same problem appears. You can test using the MQTT Client Utility that comes with MQ Explorer.

Comment: Thanks. I've been doing more investigation though, and have found the following: 1) Changing QoS to QoS0 for non-persistence avoids the error: however, we want persistence. 2) The handshaking for QoS2 was not being dealt with properly, and I've rearranged it following IBM's documentation. It's better, but still occurs (after >50 messages in quick succession). 3) If I pause for 3 seconds after sending one message, the problem never occurs. 4) The prolem seems to occur when I stop receiving (or at least hearing) PUBREL messages in response to the PUBREC messages I return.

Comment: Also, once the problem occurs, all the rest of the sent messages are queued in "Pending" and are "In Doubt Out".

Comment: I think you should raise a PMR with IBM to get this resolved.

Comment: I've tested using the IBM MQTT Client utility that comes with WebSphere, and I'm not seeing the same problems. It's not an issue with WebSphere, I think it's a problem with the library. What I want to know is any known problems that can cause what I'm seeing.

Comment: No. I am not aware of any such problem.